# What does the @data directive mean in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

I have come across the following directive in some assembly code:

```
mov    ax, @data
```

I've gone through my assembler book and tried some Googl-ing, but can't find a definition.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: equals to `mov ax,seg first_member_of_data` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@data` is a macro for the default data group, which is only relevant if you're not using the `FLAT` model.

The code you provided is typically followed by `mov ds, ax`, which sets up the data segment register for the current executable.

(MSDN reference at [@data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a438740c.aspx).)

Comment: Ah, yes, this makes sense since the code was using the 16-bit registers and the book was also referring to the real + flat mode...author just magically introduced it without explaining.  Thanks!

Comment: "Why do we use @data" link leads to a poem. Is this some kind of a joke?

Comment: @MayankVerma Not a joke, just a link that has apparently changed since the original post. I've removed it.