# Getting error after copying 8086 code from book

Tags: x86-16, emu8086

I am having troubles running this 8086 programs that take one letter input from keyboard and outputs "the letter you typed is _"

I just started reading my college book on this and trying to run some code from the book on my computer but got stuck here.

The code below is from my college book.
I am running it in emu8086 emulator.

```
CODE SEGMENT
            ; set the DS register
MOV AX, DATA
MOV DS, AX
            ; Read Keyboard
MOV AH, 08H
INT 21H
            ; Save input
MOV BL, AL
            ; Display first part of Message
MOV AH, 09H
MOV DX, OFFSET MESSAGE
INT 21H
            ; Display character of BL register
MOV AH, 02H
MOV DL, BL
INT 21H
            ; Exit to DOS
MOV AX, 4C00H
INT 21H

CODE ENDS
DATA SEGMENT
     MESSAGE DB “The letter you typed is $”
DATA ENDS
END
```

The error I am getting is

```
INT 21h, AH=09h - 
address: 00020
byte 24h not found after 2000 bytes.
; correct example of INT 21h/9h:
mov dx, offset msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
ret
msg db "Hello$"
```

After further debugging by myself I have concluded there is some problem with this

```
MOV AX, DATA
MOV DS, AX
```

If I remove it from my code it executes but with some garbage in the start.

[image: Output after removing those statements]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Update:
Image of emulator around the string "the letter you typed $"
[image: Image of emulator around the string "the letter you typed $]

Comment: Your source does include an ASCII `$` character (`24h`) that terminates DOS print-string, but the quotes aren't normal ASCII double quotes `”` is unicode `e2 80 9d`.  Check memory contents with the debugger as you single-step your code and see what's there around that "*The letter you typed is $*" text.

Comment: Also, does emu8086 really accept `INT 21 H` as equivalent to `INT 21H`, with the hex suffix separated from the number by a space?

Comment: are you sure this are 8086 commands? I don't remember having macros like message and data segment in the instruction set of 8086.

Comment: @Daniel: `message` is a label and segments are a basic feature of 8086 assembly.

Comment: @Daniel it will work without data segment too. and message is the variable name(or the equivalent in assembly)

Comment: @PeterCordes I have formatted and added a image showing the emu around the string you asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928538/what-does-the-data-directive-mean-in-masm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

umm so after giving up for 2 days I referenced another book, and in there they weren't using segments. So I removed segments and the program ran flawlessly here is the new code:

```
ORG 100H

MOV AH, 08H ; Read Keyboard
INT 21H
            
MOV BL, AL  ; Save input
            
MOV AH, 09H ; Display first part of Message
MOV DX, OFFSET MESSAGE
INT 21H
            
MOV AH, 02H  ; Display character of BL register
MOV DL, BL
INT 21H
            
MOV AX, 4C00H ; Exit to DOS
INT 21H

RET


MESSAGE DB "The letter you typed is $"
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me, really appreciated.

Comment: That's source for a `.com` executable which starts with all segment registers set the same ("tiny" memory model), so yes, you don't need to mess around with segmentation and can learn that later, once you understand the rest of asm.  (Or not at all since it's irrelevant for modern CPUs which just use wider addresses).  Your question had source for a `.exe` executable which needs to set DS to be able to access its `.data` section/segment.

Comment: @PeterCordes mate thnx alot!!!, I just opened a new file with exe and there was a template with segments and it ran flawlessly but my original code still showed the same problem so after messing around with it I figured it out I was missing this code ```stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0) ``` after this my original code ran too. thnx for your help!!